# Weighted binary cross entropy dice loss for segmentation problem

Tags: python, keras, image-segmentation, loss, cross-entropy

I am using weighted Binary cross entropy Dice loss for a segmentation problem with class imbalance (80 times more black pixels than white pixels) .

```
def weighted_bce_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.cast(y_true, 'float32')
    y_pred = K.cast(y_pred, 'float32')
    averaged_mask = K.pool2d(
        y_true, pool_size=(50, 50), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', pool_mode='avg')
    weight = K.ones_like(averaged_mask)
    w0 = K.sum(weight)
    weight = 5. * K.exp(-5. * K.abs(averaged_mask - 0.5))
    w1 = K.sum(weight)
    weight *= (w0 / w1)
    loss = weighted_bce_loss(y_true, y_pred, weight) + dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss
```

Dice coeffecient increased and the loss decreased but at every epoch I am getting a black image as output (all the pixels are labelled black)

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: "Found 60 images belonging to 1 classes"?

Comment: It is a segmentation problem. So it is pixelwise binary classification.

Comment: What happens if you use a non-Dice weighted cross-entropy (i.e. `loss = 'binary_crossentropy'` and `class_weight = {0: 1 / 81, 1: 80 / 81}`?

Comment: Hey @AKSHAYAAVAIDYANATHAN were you able to resolve this issue? If so, would you care to share it?